# What's the maximal length of string that's going to be hashed?

Tags: hash, sha1

I wonder... what's the maximal length of string that's going to be hashed?

For example, to hash `Hello, world!` with SHA-1 is no problems. But what about string that's like 100'000'000 chars long? Does it even work? Does it somehow increase collision possibility?

Are there any limits?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) shows max message size in bits for SHA-1 as 2^64−1. So, this would be 2^60-1 unicode characters. In decimal 1,152,921,504,606,846,975 characters.

Most language string limits are 2GB - 1 characters.

Collision probability is subject to the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), specifically the "Probability table" bit. I'm <strike>not clever enough</strike> too lazy to work the probability for collisions using SHA-1 with a collection of 100MB strings...

Comment: Probability of collisions depends on how many strings you hash, not on the individual length of each string. You will get no collision at all with a single string, since you then have only one value...

Comment: @Thomas Pornin: yep, I said "a collection of 100MB strings". And it would be a fairly large collection too with all the permuatations etc

Answer (score 4):

You can hash long inputs.  Yes, hash algorithms still work on large inputs.  No, a larger input doesn't increase collision probability.  (But they'll take longer.)  You should keep in mind that 100 million characters isn't that many bytes for a computer, and most hashes in use today are *fast*.  It would take a modern computer maybe a few seconds to hash a string that long.

There are no theoretical limits, and the practical limits allow for any reasonable use.